# How do I print a hash in perl?

Tags: string, perl, hash, dereference

How do I print $stopwords? It seems to be a string ($) but when I print it I get: "HASH(0x8B694)" with the memory address changing on each run.

I am using Lingua::StopWords and I simply want to print the stop words that it's using so I know for sure what stop words are there. I would like to print these two a file.

Do I need to deference the $stopwords some how?

Here is the code:

```
use Lingua::StopWords qw( getStopWords );

open(TEST, ">results_stopwords.txt") or die("Unable to open requested file.");
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');

print $stopwords;
```

I've tried:

```
my @temp = $stopwords;
print "@temp";
```

But that doesn't work. Help!

Last note: I know there is a list of stop words for Lingua::StopWords, but I am using the (en) and I just want to make absolute sure what stop words I am using, so that is why I want to print it and ideally I want to print it to a file which the file part I should already know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to dereference a hashref :

```
%hash = %{$hashref};  # makes a copy
```

so to iterate over keys values

```
while(($key,$value)=each%{$hashref}){
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

or (less efficient but didactic purpose)

```
for $key (keys %{$hashref}){
    print "$key => $hashref->{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`$` doesn't mean string. It means a scalar, which could be a string, number or reference.

`$stopwords` is a hash reference. To use it as a hash, you would use `%$stopwords`.

Use `Data::Dumper` as a quick way to print the contents of a hash (pass by reference):

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
print Dumper($stopwords);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter) as a nice alternative to Data::Dumper. It will give you pretty-printed output as well as information on methods which the object provides (if you're printing an object).  So, whenever you don't know what you've got:

```
use Data::Printer;
p( $some_thing );
```

You'll be surprised at how handy it is.

Answer (score 1):

`getStopWords` returns a hash**ref** — a reference to a hash — so you would dereference it by prepending `%`. And you actually only want its keys, not its values (which are all `1`), so you would use the `keys` function. For example:

```
print "$_\n" foreach keys %$stopwords;
```

or

```
print join(' ', keys %$stopwords), "\n";
```

You can also skip the temporary variable `$stopwords`, but then you need to wrap the `getStopWords` call in curly-brackets `{...}` so Perl can tell what's going on:

```
print join(' ', keys %{getStopWords('en')}), "\n";
```